# Cannot read property 'closeModal1' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Running into this error. Trying to open/close the modal and also updating the state once it is either open or closed. Been stuck for a bit now and I cant seem to figure it out.Haven't tried many things since I haven't been able to find anything related with what I'm trying to do on google or with stackoverflow. I'm still a newbie so forgive me if the code makes you sick ha ha. Thanks in advance!

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
export const openModal1 = () => {
  return {
    type: "OPEN_MODAL"
  };
};
export const closeModal1 = () => {
  return {
    type: "CLOSE_MODAL"
  };
};



````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  modalIsOpen: false
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "OPEN_MODAL":
      return { ...state, modalIsOpen: true };
    case "CLOSE_MODAL":
      return { ...state, modalIsOpen: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import authReducer from "./authReducer";
import modalReducer from "./modalReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  vis: modalReducer
});
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The openModal1 and closeModal1 functions should be on your props. Try replacing: this.vis.openModal1() with this.props.openModal1().

Comment: After looking back at my code I'm realizing the problem I'm having is trying to figure out how I can dispatch an action to set the visibility state to false

Comment: Update your question with the code for the actions and reducers for openModal1 and closeModal1 if you want.

Comment: lol. Leave the old code up as well, I can't remember what you had. The code for reducing you modals is in the ./modalReducer file, right?

Comment: yes the code is in that file. trying to get code back up overflow being a bit of a pain.